# Помогите сформировать запрос в C# Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, xpath

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как следуя данному синтаксису получить IList всех элементов с id, которые находятся в "nobr"

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@id='viewns_Z7_9HD6HG80NOK1E0ABJMNO3H30S1_: form1:ns_Z7_9HD6HG80NOK1E0ABJMNO3H30S1_j_id1591088840_5ed612f1']/div/nobr")]

public IList<IWebElement> idList { get; set; }
```

[image: Как выглядит сайт]

Comment: `.../div/nobr/a` попробуйте

Comment: не помогло( Может как то можно сформировать запрос чтобы обнаружило все айдишники с цифрами?

Answer (score 0):

лучшее решение - собственное)

```
    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "time")]
    private IWebElement timeBox;
    public IWebElement timeBoxes(int numberOfBox)
    {
        int boxNumber = numberOfBox;
        IList<IWebElement> timeBoxes = new List<IWebElement>();
        timeBoxes = timeBox.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
        return timeBoxes[boxNumber];
    }
```